# Complex differentiable function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a complex valued function defined on a domain $D\subseteq\mathbb {C}$ and differentiable at $z_{0}\in D.$ Then my question is that is the real and imaginary part of $ f$ are also differentiable at $z_{0}=(x_{0}, y_{0})$( in the sense of real case)? I searched it  in many examples but did't get counterexample. Is it true in general? If it is true please give me the proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must have heard of the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If these are satisfied by differentiable functions (and they are) what can you say about the real and imaginary parts of $f$?

Comment: If $ f $ is differentiable then what can be said about differentiablity of its real and imaginary part ?